# Disable built-in speech recognition commands?

Tags: c#, .net, operating-system, speech-recognition

I'm trying to build software that interprets various textual commands, all in a custom way. I use System.Speech.Recognition and it works surprisingly well, but I can't figure how to get around the fact that whenever I say "Delete", "Close", "Correct", etc, I will end up with the default Windows (7) implementation. Is there any way to get around that with System.Speech.Recognition? If not, which C# .NET library would you recommend the most?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use SpeechRecognitionEngine instead of SpeechRecognizer.

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
namespace speech
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine mynizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
        builder.AppendDictation();
        Grammar mygram = new Grammar(builder);
        mynizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        mynizer.LoadGrammar(mygram);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mynizer.Recognize().Text);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Pointing the recognizer to the default microphone and use an event handler instead of endless loop:
`mynizer.SpeechRecognized += HandleSpeechRecognized;
mynizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
mynizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);`